# How can i replace the top of the application with image, android

Tags: android, image

how can i change the top of the application, which is basically icon and name (in black activity) with image in android?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either way by showing your activity in Full Screen mode,

**Using Coding**

```
    // remove title
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

**Using Androidmanifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m guessing your question is: How can I change the App image icon on the top of the App (where the ActionBar is)?

Steps

1. Get the image u want and save it as a .png file.  So for example, “myPic.png”. Do not save it as a .jpg file!
2. Go to res/drawable-hdpi folder and delete the old image. Replace it with your image.
3. Do the same thing for “res/drawable-ldpi” image and the other drawable folder’s images. Each of the different drawable folders is for different screen sizes and resolution. So u will need different pics. If u need to change the resolution of your image, go to Paint and choose “Resize”. I set my images to the same resolution as the original android images.
4. Go into AndroidManifest.xml file and change the old android:icon= “`@drawable/ic_launcher`” (inside ) to the name of your image. So for this example android:icon= “`@drawable/myPic`”.
5. Go to the “Project” tab on the top of Eclipse IDE and then go down to “Clean…”. That will rebuilt you whole file so that the edits are saved.
6. Run ur program and see if it works. I haven’t done this in a few months so hopefully I didn’t forget any steps. Good luck. Let me know if things don’t work.

Comment: I am really sorry for the incomplete question, i'm beginner in android... What i meant was: is it possible to change the whole title bar with image, kind of a custom title bar? Sorry again for the misunderstanding, and thank you for your respond.